# Partly static and partly dynamic method parameter?

Tags: oop, generics, methods, parameters, abap

I need a method parameter with a partly generic type: some of its components should be known statically, and the rest can be generic.

Currently, my class method has an importing parameter `is_param` type `simple` which is fully generic. I would like to force the parameters passed to that method to have *at least* the components `a`, `b`, `c` in their type. Components `a`, `b`, `c` should be accessible statically inside the method like this: `is_param-a`, `is_param-c`, `is_param-c`.

The other components of the parameter will be dynamic.

How to type such a parameter ?

Comment: Do you mean OPTIONAL parameters? https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abapmethods_parameters.htm

Comment: No, that's not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to have a parameter that is partially dynamic and partially static. So you're stuck with the dynamic parameter `is_param`. You can check the parameter for the components `a` `b` and `c` via `assign component 'A' of structure is_param to <value>.` and if you have a `sy-subrc <> 0` raise an exception.

To access `a`, `b` and `c` statically (without assigning them every time) you could just define a structure with these components and move the fields over from `is_param`. Then you can use that structure whenever you need access to those fields.

```
  method do_something.

    data: begin of ls_static,
             a type char1,
             b type char1,
             c type char1,
           end of ls_static.
    move-corresponding is_param to ls_static.
  *  use ls_static for a,b and c...
    
  *  if it's a changing parameter move a,b and c back:
    move-corresponding ls_static to is_param.
  endmethod.
```

If `is_param` is a changing parameter you have to move them back to from `ls_static` at the end. In this case you have to be careful not to change `a,b,c` in `is_param` or use them from there then since you could have different states in `is_param` and `ls_static` then.

*Note: There is maybe a way to use a class to achive this since you can access global attributes with `object->attribute`. So you could use this to access your static components and store the rest of the data in that class too. I gave it a try but couldn't find a good way to actually achive anything that's easier to use or more convenient then the solution above.*